# How can a normal user trigger a root cron task to execute immediately, without delay?

Tags: process, sudo, cron, java, non-root-user

I have a root cron task that runs every day. But I want to allow normal users to request that it run immediately, if they so wish. It is a harmless process and it can run as often as needed and these normal users are actually trusted users. But I don't want to give these normal users any special permissions.

Can I allow a normal user to trigger the cron task to run immediately? If so, how? The user will be doing this via a Java app, so I'll probably be using Java's ProcessBuilder.

ProcessBuilder (Java 2 Platform SE 5.0)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

I would be great if you can provide a solution with Java ProcessBuilder example code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As variant - create a script (added to crontab) and allow to execute without password
https://askubuntu.com/questions/155791/how-do-i-sudo-a-command-in-a-script-without-being-asked-for-a-password

Answer (score 1):

You can allow everyone to call this process in addition to (i.e. independently of) the run caused by `cron`.

Just allow the execution (without password) via `sudo`, create a wrapper script which does the `sudo` call and point the users at this script.

Comment: Can you provide full details and an example, please? Thanks.

Comment: @MountainX The link in the other answer does that.

Comment: it doesn't provide enough detail, so I asked a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21820343/463994